# Why are my previous post(s) marked with "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them." on search engines?

Tags: bug

The reason is because I asked a question (for a feature request and deleted my question thereafter).

This user does not prefer to keep an "air of mystery".

Comment: Huh? Your profile page might have that, but no posts should...

Comment: Yes, that's what his profile page says ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's the default if you don't write anything about yourself. Many other users have the exact same wording on their profile page.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251810/the-site-should-not-make-speculative-statements-about-its-users

Comment: It is unclear whether you are talking about search engine hits cataloguing your profile, or actual posts of yours. Can you point to a specific search engine query, or show some specific search results?

Comment: Can you let us know which _posts_ that phrase is being attached to in search results? I can't find it anywhere but profiles. I'm wondering if you're seeing some kind of 'one boxing' from Yahoo / Bing / Yandex or something (I looked, but I couldn't find anything)

Comment: @TimPost still, it shouldn't be attached to profile results either. As has been repeatedly said here and on meta.SE, the "about me" should simply be left blank or filled with an unambiguous wording that does not try to be funny. If it's prominently featured in google results, that's one more reason why a misguided attempt at humor is simply out of place here.

Comment: My bad. I meant to put that in as a comment and not as an answer. So That's Just the default text then? I was wondering.

Comment: Also, I meant for this answer to actually be a comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: To clarify, I was seeing the "air of mystery" note on some of my top posts as well as my profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

The *search engine* shows exactly what your **about me** section in your *profile* looks like. Apparently you are looking at the shorter version of the about me section in the searched links which shows up your user profile.

- Profile

[image]

- Google search

[image]

I don't see a firm reason that you are describing it as a *bug*. Seems to be a normal search engine behavior. *You get what you ask for!*

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that was default